# Azure StatefulService not deploying locally due to failure to load

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

The deployment of an Azure Statefulservice is failing with the following output:

```
Service Status:
fabric:/Cloud.Application/MyServiceStateless is ready.
fabric:/Cloud.Application/MyServiceStateful is not ready, 1 partitions remaining.

Something is taking too long, the application is still not ready.
Finished executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'
```

This is strange since no other member of my team has seen this problem.  To help diagnose it, I set a breakpoint at Program.Main(), but the breakpoint was not hit.  Instead, the message "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  A copy of Program.cs was found in StatelessServiceXYZ.exe, but the current source code is different from the version built into StatelessServiceXYZ.exe" when the mouse is hovered over they whited out breakpoint circle.  This indicates the assembly isn't loading.

Because no one else can reproduce this problem even though our environments are seemingly identical (we're all using Visual Studio 2017,  Microsoft Azure ServiceFabric CoreSDK, .Net Frameword 4.5, and Windows 7), it appears there is some configuration difference or problem with my machine.  The other solutions to this problem that I've found online, such as lack of disk space, etc., are not applicable to my situation.  I've also tried resetting the local cluster to no avail.  Deploying a test StatefulService also worked.

Answer (score 1):

I find a similar issue in the [github](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/619). if updating the netcore runtime is acceptable, you could have a try to update projects to the [2.0.3](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/releases/tag/v2.0.3) runtime service.